# Tkinter: assigning entry to a variable returns None

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am getting None as name and age from the entry of Tkinter and I can't make it work. Please, what is wrong?
The following code is identical with the one used in this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PHJvjQJa3w&ab_channel=edureka%21):

```py
from tkinter import *  
from tkinter import Entry

main_window = Tk()

Label(main_window, text="Enter your name  ").grid(row=0, column=0)  
Label(main_window, text="What's your age  ").grid(row=1, column=0)

my_name = Entry(main_window, width=30, borderwidth=5).grid(row=0, column=1)  
my_age = Entry(main_window, width=30, borderwidth=5).grid(row=1, column=1)

def on_click():  
    print(f'My name is {my_name}, and my age is {my_age}.')

Button(main_window, text='Click Me', command=on_click).grid(row=2, column=1)

main_window.mainloop()
```

I read on youtube and here to try the get method, but I am just starting with programming, and I must be doing something wrong because nothing is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value from a call to `.grid()` method is None.  So both of the variables `my_age` and `my_name` value once the line has finished processing is `None` and you no longer have a reference variable for the widgets. you need to split up the calls that create the objects and the call to `grid`.

The same would be true for the labels also if you needed to keep a reference to them after they have been created.  But since you don't you can leave those lines the way they are.

```py
from tkinter import *  
from tkinter import Entry

main_window = Tk()

Label(main_window, text="Enter your name  ").grid(row=0, column=0)  
Label(main_window, text="What's your age  ").grid(row=1, column=0)

my_name = Entry(main_window, width=30, borderwidth=5)
my_name.grid(row=0, column=1)  
my_age = Entry(main_window, width=30, borderwidth=5)
my_age.grid(row=1, column=1)

def on_click():  
    print(f'My name is {my_name}, and my age is {my_age}.')

Button(main_window, text='Click Me', command=on_click).grid(row=2, column=1)

main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but now I get:  "My name is .!entry, and my age is .!entry2."

Comment: Thats because you need to add `.get()` to the end of both my_age and my_name when you are trying to retreive their values.  @CaioMonteiro